# Need help understanding the fluent wait Java code

Tags: selenium, functional-interface, fluentwait

I am trying to understand the Java code associated with fluent Wait in Selenium. The code goes as below:

```
WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

I know that the overall code is waiting for a particular WebElement to be returned by the until method. But my doubt is pertaining to the below code piece.

```
new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
         public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
           return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
         }
       }
```

I also understand the Function is an in-built Functional Interface that takes WebDriver as input and returns the WebElement as output. But how does the *new* keyword fit into the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

Fluent Wait uses two parameters – timeout value and polling frequency.

**1.** The maximum amount of time to wait for a condition

**2.** The frequency to check the success or failure of a specified condition.

Also, if you want to configure the wait to ignore exceptions such as , then you can add it to the Fluent Wait command syntax.

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)    
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)    
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)   
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {    
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {    
        return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));    
    }
});
```

*analyze of the above sample code.*

**1.** Fluent Wait starts with capturing the start time to determine the delay.

**2.** Fluent Wait then checks the condition defined in the until() method.

**3.** If the condition fails, Fluent Wait makes the application to wait as per the value set by the `pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)` method call. Here in this example, it’s 5 seconds.

**4.** After the wait defined in Step 3 expires, the start time is checked against the current time. If the difference of the wait start time (set in step-1) and the current time is less than the time set in `withTimeout(30, SECONDS`) method, then Step-2 will need to repeat.

The above steps will recur until either the timeout expires or the condition becomes true.

**Function is the functional interface**

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Function<T, R> {

/**
 * Applies this function to the given argument.
 *
 * @param t the function argument
 * @return the function result
 */
R apply(T t);

/**
 * Returns a composed function that first applies the {@code before}
 * function to its input, and then applies this function to the result.
 * If evaluation of either function throws an exception, it is relayed to
 * the caller of the composed function.
 *
 * @param <V> the type of input to the {@code before} function, and to the
 *           composed function
 * @param before the function to apply before this function is applied
 * @return a composed function that first applies the {@code before}
 * function and then applies this function
 * @throws NullPointerException if before is null
 *
```

Comment: Sorry but the answer is what i already know and not something I was looking for. I am trying to understand what the Function part o the code relates to in terms of Java.

Comment: Not looking for Java documentation as already been there